# How to call a postgresql sql function in sqlalchemy in an update query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalachemy in python and i have a question.
I need to port this query:

```
UPDATE user_list SET last_visit=now()  WHERE   name='"+username+"'
```

I have read a lot about the update query, but I see possibility to set the value of the last_visit to the value generated by the now() function of postgresql. How would I do that properly? Assume that I would use the update functions of sqlalachemty. I could generate this as sql string and execute() it, but then the statement could be subject of sql injection. How to do this right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `func.now()` (import `func` from `sqlalchemy`).

Reference: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html