# Does SQLAlchemy have bool_and aggregate function?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to use `bool_and` aggregate function for GROUP BY, but I do not understand how to implement it in SQLAlchemy. I have tried `func.and_` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956867/how-to-call-a-postgresql-sql-function-in-sqlalchemy-in-an-update-query.

Answer (score 5):

You can create (almost) any SQL function expression [from `func` by its name](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html):

> Note that any name not known to [`func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) **generates the function name as is** - there is no restriction on what SQL functions can be called, known or unknown to SQLAlchemy, built-in or user defined.

So the answer is just:

```
func.bool_and(...)
```

There are some functions that are known to SQLAlchemy and get special treatment, such as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.