# How to write lead() function in sqlalchmey?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write a postgres sql function statement in sqlalchemy

**lead(column)**

I have looked at func, it doesn't have lead(). Any pointers on how I can write this in sqlalchemy?

Comment: `func` will generate the function name as is for any SQL function unknown to SQLAlchemy. See [SQL and Generic Functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html)

Comment: On using window functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598610/using-the-over-window-function-in-sqlalchemy. About `func`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343523/does-sqlalchemy-have-bool-and-aggregate-function

Comment: Thank you @benvc. I just used func.lead() and it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
LEAD(col_1) OVER (PARTITION BY col_2 ORDER BY col_3) AS col_4

SQLAlchemy:
func.lean(col_1).over(
    col_2,
    col_3
).label('col_4')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.